# Key-repeat does not work after running OpenGL program with nvidia-331-updates on Ubuntu 14.10x64

Tags: drivers, nvidia, keyboard, xorg, opengl

earlier today I switched to the proprietary NVidia drivers to be able to develop some programs with OpenGL4.2+. Since then I have noticed various changes to the system, e.g. the mousewheel is much more sensitive (and thus scrolls much faster) and key-repeat does not work (i.e. holding down the button 'a' will not emit multiple a's, not matter how long it is pressed). I can restore the key-repeat functionality by executing

```
xkbset repeatkeys
```

or

```
xset r rate 300 30
```

but this effect is only temporary. As soon as I launch an OpenGL application, key-repeat will stop working.

I guess all this is related to `xorg` and its configuration files but I was neither able to find a way to add key-repeat as a feature to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` (which I created using `nvidia-xconfig` in order to see whether I could tinker with it to solve my problems) nor to tell the NVidia drivers to just ignore its xorg-configuration (which would probably break its main functionality anyways).

I am thankful for any suggestions.

-S.

**Edit:** To clarify the question: Why does the NVidia driver mess with key-repeat and how to make it stop doing that?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! ;-) And, please, blame it on me: I'm confused...  But...  What's your question? :/

Comment: Thank you for your feedback :). I edited the OP to further clarify the question.

Comment: what's the output for `nvidia-settings --version`?

Comment: @Fabby: version 331.20  (buildd@roseapple)  Mon Feb  3 15:07:22 UTC 2014

Comment: OK, How technical are you?  Do you know what a PPA is and does and do you know what rolling software versions forward and backward is?  Furthermore: what TZ are you in?

Comment: @Fabby: I'd say I am reasonably technically versed. I have been programming for a good few years and am very much familiar with the structure of computers in general; I have only been using Linux for a few years and have been trying to avoid to delve deeper into it than needed. I am in GMT+1. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The standard Ubuntu NVidia drivers generate some problems on slightly older *and* slightly newer NVidia hardware.

If you want *more* then the standard Ubuntu repository drivers, install the [xorg.edgers](https://launchpad.net/~xorg-edgers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) PPA.  As the xorg.edgers group ask not to give installation instructions directly without linking to their page, this is the best I can do (for now)

So please read the warning sign and then add the PPA (**using your own judgement!  Never let anyone tell you what to do with your own machine!)  Then do an `apt-get update` and then install the driver you want (I'm currently running 346.22 and very happy about it!)

Comment: And if you need more guidance, drop me a note @Fabby and we'll take it up in chat.

Comment: Thank you! Installation worked fine, but the problem is still present. Furthermore, I now have a flickering terminal when using autocompletion, so I will probably revert to 331.

Comment: Hold on!  You now have a ton of drivers to choose from!  You don't have to revert back to 331. but can go to 343 or...  do an `apt-cache search nvidia | grep --ignore-case binary` to see all your drivers!

Comment: Also, you didn't click the little grey check-mark below the "0", (which means: I accept the answer) so I missed that you were actually doing this...

Comment: I'll go through the other drivers to see if any of them solve my problem. While I am very thankful for your suggestions and help, the check-mark very clearly states that only answers that led to a solution should be marked as accepted. I have no solution yet and I will accept your answer as soon as I have verified that it works with some other driver :)

Comment: Danke!  Mehr frage ich nicht!  :P  ;-) It's just that some of the newbies buzz off and never return until they have another problem, forgot the previous login, and: *create a new one!*  >:) That's why I keep pestering my rep1's